# Swift 4 animate constraint triggerd by pan gesture

Tags: swift

I've got a pan gesture on top of my tableView and implemented the following delegate method to keep the original scroll behaviour.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

In the pan gesture selector, I'm modifying a constraint using some calculations that won't matter for the problem. These constraints get's updated immediately without calling `layoutIfNeeded()`.

This is fine when the user is scrolling super slow, but I want to animate the disappearing of the constraint when the offset is higher or equal to 94 pixels. When this happens I always set the constraint to 94.

I tried to set the constant value in an animation block, using UIView.beginAnimations, calling it on a async main thread but all of them apply the constraint constant immediately.

When I modify the frame origin, the animation works. How can I make the animation work using constraints? I dislike the updating of frame origin since I'm using AutoLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, if you call `layoutIfNeeded()` in the animation block from the parent view. It will get animated :)